# Jerry looks under the chair and, seeing both coins says, "At least one of them is tails." What is the probability that Tia wins?

Tags: probability

> Tia and Jerry are tossing two coins. Tia wins when both coins turn up tails. The coins are tossed but roll under a chair. Jerry looks under the chair and, seeing both coins says, "At least one of them is tails." What is the probability that Tia wins?

Because it says **at least** I know I should be doing $1 -$ however, I'm not sure how to apply this, the odds of the other coin being tails is $1/2$, so wouldn't you say the probability of Tia winning be $50\%$, because it's based off that one coin?

Comment: HINT: There are $3$ equally likely options: TT, TH, HT.

Comment: @barakmanos, what about HH though? Or is this only outcomes with tails as oppose to total number of outcomes?

Comment: Well, Jerry  already saw a tail, right? So how can it be HH?

Comment: @barakmanos ahh, you're right! Sorry, I'm not very math inclined(my worst subject) I'm an idiot.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things come down to phrasing.  A priori there are $4$ equally likely states of the world:  $HH,HT, TH, TT$ .  Jerry's comment is probably best interpreted as "$HH$ did not occur."  In that case there are three equally likely outcomes remaining and, as Tia wins in exactly one of these, the answer is $\frac 13$.

It's very different if Jerry says "the coin on the left came up $T$."  Then your argument holds and the answer is $\frac 12$.  Otherwise said, the possible states would then be $TH$ or $TT$.

Comment: So i guess when I read these types of questions, I should read them very carefully and over multiple times, funny how a simple sentence can alter the entire question :)

Comment: It gets worse than this, read about [The Monty Hall Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) for example.  People still argue about that.

Comment: Follow up questions to think about: (1) What if Jerry only says "the coin on the left came up tails" if both coins were tails, and otherwise says "at least one coin is tails?"  Then what are the odds?  (2) What if Jerry is a liar?  (The point: you can't compute on the basis of the statement without knowing the *rules by which the statement was made.*)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! Just because a problem says "at least" one does not mean you do "$1-$"! There are problems where "at least one" has to be approached directly.

There are a couple of ways to think about this.

1. If I call $N$ the number of heads in two tosses, then the probability of interest is
   \begin{align*}
   P(N = 2|N\geq 1)&= \frac{P(N=2, N\geq 1)}{P(N \geq 1)}\\
   &=\frac{P(N=2)}{1-P(N=0)}\\
   &=\frac{(1/2)^2}{1-(1/2)^2}\\
   &=\frac{1}{3}
   \end{align*}
2. Alternatively, notice that the possible outcomes are
   $$\text{(H,T),(H,H),(T,H),(T,T)}$$
   all equally likely. They tell us that we have at least one head, hence our outcome space has reduced to 
   $$\text{(H,T),(H,H),(T,H)}$$
   So, the probability of interest is
   $$\frac{\text{# of winning outcomes}}{\text{# possible outcomes}} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: I find probability to be very difficult due to the nature of how the questions can be asked, the idea that a single wording of a question can decide how you approach it is a scary thought!

Comment: That's why you jump in it and get your feet wet! It's not so cold. :) Consider giving respondents [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

There are $3$ equally likely options: TT, TH, HT.

Comment: Ok so it's $1/3$ because 1 of those 3 options can be picked?

Comment: @Xor: It's important to note that these three are indeed equally probable, with HT being distinct from TH.